# Add a list or feature to multiple site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, template

I've a "big" template that i've used to generate multiple site, all with the same features.

If in future i would like to add a page, list or any other sharepoint features, how can i apply to all site used from that templates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward upgrade path. The whole situation depends on how you created the initial template (save as template vs. site definition)

We normally do the updates via PowerShell to existing sites.